# Removing a directory with colon from CIFS

Tags: directory, cifs, delete

I cannot delete a directory containing a colon (using Ubuntu) on a network drive (filesystem: CIFS).
**How can I delete this directory?** (no root privileges, but do have read/write permission)

Output of `rmdir ':5N0A210'/` and `rmdir ':5N0A210'`:

```
rmdir: failed to remove ':5N0A210': No such file or directory
```

Output of `ls -li`:

```
123011781 drwxr-sr-x 2 username domain users      0 May 31 10:00 :5N0A210
```

Output of `ls -1b`:

```
:5N0A210
```

Output of `find . -inum 123011781 -delete`:

```
find: cannot delete ‘./:5N0A210’: No such file or directory
```

Output of `rename 's|:|-|g' *`:

```
Can't rename :5N0A210 -5N0A210: No such file or directory
```

I just realized I can create directory ':test' and also able to delete with no errors.

I can also create ':5N0A210' and delete it, but it is shown immediately after I refresh GUI. `ls -li` shows the same inode number as before.

I can also create ':4N0A210' (changed '5' to '4') and delete it with no errors.

All testing was done in same directory as ':5N0A210'.

Comment: You said the client is Ubuntu. What is the server?

Comment: @roaima I'm not sure. How would I check?

Comment: colon is a [reserved character for CIFS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file) so I'm not sure you'll be successful. Any idea how the file got created like that in the first place?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I was copying some files from a flash drive to the directory the `:5N0A210` resides in (not inside `:5N0A210`). I had canceled the copy midway.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Then why am I able to create ':4N0A210'?

Answer (score 0):

From the directory in which `:5N0A210` is located:

```
rm -rf ./\:5N0A210

rm -rf ':5N0A210'

rm -rf ./:5N0A210

rm -rf :5N0A210
```

These all work in my environment.

UPDATE

You can also just remove it from the server side using the above commands. If you don't have access to the server, have someone who does have that access remove it.

Comment: `rm -rf \:5N0A210` works with no output. `echo $?` returns 0. Directory is still there (according to `ls -al`)

Comment: @Inrdedix Answer updated.

Comment: Just tried all 4 separately. No output, return code 0. Are you testing with CIFS?

Comment: @Inrdedix I did it both on a cifs share and from the server itself. It doesn't matter as long as you have the permissions. The exit code being 0 also doesn't mean anything other than that the command ran without any errors. Remove `setuid` with `chmod g-s` on the directory and try it again. Worst case, go to the server itself and delete or ask someone with access to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a series of reserved characters that are not allowed in Windows filenames `\ / : * ? " < > |`. CIFS follows this rule, which means you cannot use any of those characters in a filename.

SAMBA can be configured with `vfs catia` to translate such characters into visually similar alternatives, but this isn't the default and may not be configured in your instance. (If it is, a simple shell character wildcard `?` would be enough to match the colon, ie `rmdir ?5N0A210`. But you've already tried that and it failed.)

The only other solution is to remove the directory directly on the server hosting the filesystem. If this is Windows then a filesystem check will forceably rename the directory. If it's Unix/Linux with SAMBA then a simple `rmdir` (or `rm -rf`) will suffice.

Comment: What's interesting is that I can also create ':4N0A210' and delete it with no errors.

Comment: `rmdir ?5N0A210` does match the name, but it still gives an error (`rmdir: failed to remove ':5N0A210': No such file or directory`).

Comment: @lnrdedix you have to run that on the server, not the client.